Problem with calibrating 3-axis magnetometer (ellipsoid fitting)
I have a problem regarding fitting an ellipsoid to calibrate a 3-axis magnetometer. I can translate and rotate the matrix correctly, but scaling is challenging. Right now, it only seems to scale correctly in the x-axis (ellipsoid is between -1 and 1), but the y and z are way too high (ellipsoid is between -130000 and 130000). I do not know how to fix this, maybe I am missing something. Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_raw_data = pd.read_csv('data/sensor_data.csv')
mag_data_raw = np.array(df_raw_data[['mag_x', 'mag_y', 'mag_z']])


def ellipsoid_fitting(data_points):
  x, y, z = data_points[:, 0, np.newaxis], data_points[:, 1, np.newaxis], data_points[:, 2, np.newaxis]
  
  D = np.hstack((x**2, y**2, z**2, 2*x*y, 2*x*z, 2*y*z, 2*x, 2*y, 2*z, np.ones_like(x)))
  vh = np.linalg.svd(D, full_matrices=False)[2]
  v = vh.T
  a = v[:, -1]
  
  A = np.array([
    [a[0], a[3], a[4]],
    [a[3], a[1], a[5]],
    [a[4], a[5], a[2]]
  ])
  
  center = -np.linalg.inv(A[:3, :3]) @ a[6:9]
  translation_matrix = np.eye(4)
  translation_matrix[3, :3] = center
  A_4x4 = np.zeros((4, 4))
  A_4x4[:3, :3] = A
  A_4x4[3, 3] = -1
  transformed = translation_matrix.T @ A_4x4 @ translation_matrix
  eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(transformed[:3, :3])
  radii = np.sqrt(np.abs(eigenvalues))  
  return center, radii, eigenvectors

def calibrate_data(data, center, radii, rotation):
  translated = data - center
  rotated = translated @ rotation
  print(rotated)
  scaled = rotated / radii
  return scaled

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")

print(mag_data_raw.shape)
center, radii, rotation = ellipsoid_fitting(mag_data_raw)
print(center, radii, rotation)
mag_data_cal = calibrate_data(mag_data_raw, center, radii, rotation)
#ax.scatter3D(mag_data_raw[:,0], mag_data_raw[:,1], mag_data_raw[:,2], color = "green", label = 'Raw Data')
ax.scatter3D(mag_data_cal[:, 0], mag_data_cal[:, 1], mag_data_cal[:, 2], color='red', label='Calibrated Data')
ax.legend()

plt.title("raw vs calibrated data")
 
plt.show()

I tried many different techniques to calibrate the magnetometer data, this one seemed to work for me, except for the scaling.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
